# Derivative with respect to a 2-norm

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

Given $f = f(u(t), t)$, is it possible to find the following derivative? ($f$,$u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$)

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial||u||^2_2}
$$

I am aware of the following derivatives:

$$
\frac{\partial||x||^2_2}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial ||x^Tx||_2}{\partial x} = 2x
$$

So I can invert it to give me (elementwise division in the RHS)

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial||x||^2_2} = \frac{1}{2x}
$$

This step does feel like abuse of notation I find it hard to convince myself of its validity.

If it's right though, I could just apply the chain rule to find

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial||u||^2_2}
$$

However, knowing that both $f$ and $u$ are a function of $t$, I am somehow doubting my own reasoning. Or does that just mean that the derivative will still be a function of $t$ and I have nothing to worry about? Can anyone shed some light?

UPDATE: I'm now doubting the existence of

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial ||u||^2_2}
$$

because $u = u(||u||_2^2)$ is not injective. Is the inversion step I did above legitimate? Is there another possible approach?

Answer (score 1):

Write the vector $u$ in spherical radial coordinates
$$\eqalign{
 u &= \mu\,e_u \cr
du &= e_u\,d\mu + \mu\,de_u \cr
}$$ 
I'll assume your question is about how the function changes in response to changing the length ($\mu$) of the vector, while the direction ($e_u$) of the vector remains constant.

Start by taking differentials 
$$\eqalign{
 d\mu^2 &= 2\,\mu\,d\mu \cr
df &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\,dt +\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\,du\cr  
   &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\,dt +\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\,(e_u\,d\mu + \mu\,de_u) \cr
}$$
Setting $(de_u, dt)$ to zero leaves
$$\eqalign{
df &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\,e_u\,d\mu \cr
}$$
For some reason, you wanted the derivative with respect to $\mu^2$, so let's make that substitution
$$\eqalign{
df &=  \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\,\frac{u}{2\mu^2}\,d\mu^2 \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mu^2} &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\,\, \frac{u}{2\mu^2} \cr
}$$